# Filtering an array of objects from an array of Strings

Tags: javascript, node.js

I have an array of Strings `var allEmojis  = [dog, toucan, flamingo, lion, tiger, duck, elephant, zebra]`and an array of objects as displayed that I obtained from mongoose. Each object in the array of objects has the attribute emoji which is filtered from the allEmojis array. (Below is the array of objects)

[image]

I would like to filter the array like so:

let's assume that the array of objects is simply: 'ArrayOfObjects'

```
 var JohnsEmojis = allEmojis.filter(function(emoji) {
  return !ArrayOfObjects.includes(emoji) /*=>>> where the object in ArrayOfObjects
    containing the emoji has an id of John not yoyoyo (yes i know, dumb name); */ 
  }) 

 var yoyoyoEmojis = allEmojis.filter(function(emoji) {
  return !ArrayOfObjects.includes(emoji) /*=>>> where the object in ArrayOfObjects
    containing the emoji has an id of yoyoyo not John; */ 
  })
```

My code fails on two counts. You cannot use the `include` on an array of objects with an array of string. Also assuming this did work, it does not filter based on the objects that have the specified id. I was hoping I could find the most efficient way to do this.

Comment: Can you describe specifically and in words what you're trying to achieve? You want to filter allEmoji's by what? whether the other array contains that emoji? What do the ids have to do with it?

Comment: I have an array containing all the emojis. I have an array of objects with each element having an id and an emoji. In the image above, you can see John has emojis flamingo and duck. So i need an array of emojis for John which filters all the emojis from johns emojis. So all emojis = [dog, toucan, flamingo, lion, tiger, duck, elephant, zebra], john's emojis = [flamingo, duck]. So filtered should be [dog, toucan, lion, tiger, elephant, zebra]. The same thing applies with the elements that have yoyoyo. I need an array for yoyoyo which filters all emojis from the emojis that yoyoyo has.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You wrote your `allEmojis` without quotes

```
var allEmojis  = [dog, toucan, flamingo, lion, tiger, duck, elephant, zebra]
```

Array of strings would be

```
var allEmojis  = ["dog", "toucan", "flamingo", "lion", "tiger", "duck", "elephant", "zebra"]
```

If this is not a problem and `allEmojis` really contains a strings, which are in `arrayOfObjects` in every object under key `object.emoji`, then you can filter intersection of `allEmojis` with `arrayOfObjects` like so

```
var filtered = allEmojis.filter(function(e) {
    return !!arrayOfObjects.find(function(o) {
        return o.emoji === e;
    });
};
```

You can also write it as

```
var filtered = arrayOfObjects
    .filter(function(o) { return allEmojis.includes(o.emoji) })
    .map(function(o) { return o.emoji }); // convert objects to strings
```

which probably has better performance.