# filter an arrays of objects from an array of strings

Tags: javascript

I'm aware there are similar questions but none have been able to help me thus far - [filtering an array of objects from and array of strings](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41320560/filtering-an-array-of-objects-from-an-array-of-strings) relies on you knowing the key value pair you would like to match, and same with this question [here](http://filtering-an-array-of-objects-by-an-array-of-strings)

Say I have an array of objects like so..

```
let users = [
    {
       name: 'Steve',
       age: 42,
       pets: {
           dog: 'spike';
       },
       favouriteFood: 'apples'
    },
    {
       name: 'Steve',
       age: 32,
       pets null
       favouriteFood: 'icecream'
    },
    {
       name: 'Jason',
       age: 31,
       pets: null
       favouriteFood: 'tacos'
    },
    {
       name: 'Jason',
       age: 31,
       pets: {
          cat: 'Jerry'
       },
       favouriteFood: 'bread'
    },
]
```

now I would like to be able to filter the array of users by matching a string in any of the objects keys. For example I want to filter out anyone whos name isnt 'steve' - keep in mind I may also want to filter out anyone who isnt 42 or who's favourite food isn't 'apples'

```
filter(term) {
    return objects.filter(x => {
        for(let key of Object.keys(x)) {
          if(typeof(x[key]) === 'object') {
              return JSON.stringify(x[key]).toLowerCase().includes(t);
          } else {
             return x[key].toString().toLowerCase().includes(t);
          }
        }
    });
}
```

now this function works but for only a single filter term

so If I ran `filter('steve')` I would then get

```
users = [
    {
       name: 'Steve',
       age: 42,
       pets: {
           dog: 'spike';
       },
       favouriteFood: 'apples'
    },
    {
       name: 'Steve',
       age: 32,
       pets null
       favouriteFood: 'icecream'
    }
]
```

as my result, but what If I wanted to filter out steve whos favourite food is apples?

I have tried to update my function as follows to loop through an array of terms and filter according to all the strings in the array

So I have tried

```
function filter(terms) {
    return term.forEach((t) => {
      return objects.filter(x => {
        for(let key of Object.keys(x)) {
          if(typeof(x[key]) === 'object') {
              return JSON.stringify(x[key]).toLowerCase().includes(t);
          } else {
             return x[key].toString().toLowerCase().includes(t);
          }
        }
      });
    });
```

but when I run `filter(['steve', 'apples'])`

I get `undefined`

My desired result would be

```
users = [
    {
       name: 'Steve',
       age: 42,
       pets: {
           dog: 'spike';
       },
       favouriteFood: 'apples'
    }
]
```

I'm not entirely sure what I'm doing wrong or how I could fix this function so it works correctly.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: If you want to filter by name, why aren't you using the much simpler: `let steves = users.filter(item => item.name.toLowerCase() === "steve")` You can just add another test to filter by favorite food.

Comment: @MarkMeyer I don't want to filter by name I want to be able to filter by anything, I am just using a simple user object as an example

Comment: forEach method is not supposed to return anything but just run the iterator soon the array. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach

Comment: I see, I was confused by `I want to filter these users by name`.

Comment: @MarkMeyer sorry for the confusion, I will re-word the question. I meant it purely as an example

Comment: Your question isn't very clear. Are you wanting to match only on string **values** (nested or otherwise)? What about object property names? For example, would you want to search for users with dogs?

Comment: @Phil yes sorry pretty much only the string values the key name is unimportant

Comment: What about partial matches? Eg, should _"Stev"_ match anything?

Comment: @Phil yes it should, I thought that was clear by using `.includes()` instead of `===` so If I searched `ste` steve would still be returned

Comment: Yeah, but your example would also match key names (for the nested objects) so that's why it wasn't clear. Thanks for clarifying

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Filter by whether `.every` value in the array of values needed is included in the `Object.values` of a given user:

```js
const filter = arrOfValsNeeded => users.filter(user => {
  const vals = Object.values(user).map(val => typeof val === 'string' ? val.toLowerCase() : val);
  return arrOfValsNeeded.every(needed => vals.includes(needed.toLowerCase()));
});

let users = [
    {
       name: 'Steve',
       age: 42,
       pets: {
           dog: 'spike'
       },
       favouriteFood: 'apples'
    },
    {
       name: 'Steve',
       age: 32,
       pets: null,
       favouriteFood: 'icecream'
    },
    {
       name: 'Jason',
       age: 31,
       pets: null,
       favouriteFood: 'tacos'
    },
    {
       name: 'Jason',
       age: 31,
       pets: {
          cat: 'Jerry'
       },
       favouriteFood: 'bread'
    },
]

console.log(filter(['steve', 'apples']));
```

Or, if you need to recursively find all primitive values:

```js
const allPrimitives = obj => {
  const primitives = [];
  JSON.stringify(obj, (key, val) => {
    if (typeof val !== 'object' || val === null) {
      primitives.push(typeof val === 'string' ? val.toLowerCase() : val);
    }
    return val;
  });
  return primitives;
};
const filter = arrOfValsNeeded => users.filter(user => {
  const vals = allPrimitives(user);
  return arrOfValsNeeded.every(needed => vals.includes(needed.toLowerCase()));
});

let users = [
    {
       name: 'Steve',
       age: 42,
       pets: {
           dog: 'spike'
       },
       favouriteFood: 'apples'
    },
    {
       name: 'Steve',
       age: 32,
       pets: null,
       favouriteFood: 'icecream'
    },
    {
       name: 'Jason',
       age: 31,
       pets: null,
       favouriteFood: 'tacos'
    },
    {
       name: 'Jason',
       age: 31,
       pets: {
          cat: 'Jerry'
       },
       favouriteFood: 'bread'
    },
]

console.log(filter(['steve', 'apples']));
```

If you need partial matches as well, use `vals.some` instead of `vals.includes` so you can identify substrings:

```js
const allStrings = obj => {
  const strings = [];
  JSON.stringify(obj, (key, val) => {
    if (typeof val === 'string') {
      strings.push(val.toLowerCase());
    }
    return val;
  });
  return strings;
};
const filter = arrOfValsNeeded => {
  const lowerVals = arrOfValsNeeded.map(str => str.toLowerCase());
  return users.filter(user => {
    const existingStrings = allStrings(user);
    return lowerVals.every(
      lowerNeeded => existingStrings.some(
        existingString => existingString.includes(lowerNeeded)
      )
    );
  });
};

let users = [
    {
       name: 'Steve',
       age: 42,
       pets: {
           dog: 'spike'
       },
       favouriteFood: 'apples'
    },
    {
       name: 'Steve',
       age: 32,
       pets: null,
       favouriteFood: 'icecream'
    },
    {
       name: 'Jason',
       age: 31,
       pets: null,
       favouriteFood: 'tacos'
    },
    {
       name: 'Jason',
       age: 31,
       pets: {
          cat: 'Jerry'
       },
       favouriteFood: 'bread'
    },
]

console.log(filter(['steve', 'apples']));
```

Comment: Hey Sorry, My question was a little unclear, basically I need it to match partial words so If I typed 'ste', 'app' It would still return steve who likes apples - I will update my question. I assumed since I used `.includes()` and not `===` it was clear. Sorry

Comment: Are the values you're looking for always strings?

Comment: @SmokeyDawson performance is really going to suffer if you continue trying to do this in the front-end (especially with a large data set). Have you considered some sort of indexing service in the backend?

Comment: @CertainPerformance the values I'm looking for will always be strings, but the data may have booleans, objects, arrays - but I'm only trying to match on the strings

Comment: @SmokeyDawson See edit, use `.some` instead of `.includes` so you can run a test for each value

Comment: @CertainPerformance thank you! this is exactly what I was looking for!

Answer (score 1):

Sorry for the late response. I kept trying to come up with recursive code that would work in almost any situation. I eventually found some really cool snippets [here](https://30secondsofcode.org/object), which is where I derived the `similar` function from `equals`, with slight considerations for compatibility.

```js
function similar(a, b){
  if(a === b){
    return true;
  }
  if(a instanceof Date && b instanceof Date){
    return a.getTime() === b.getTime();
  }
  if (!a || !b || (typeof a !== 'object' && typeof b !== 'object')){
    return a === b;
  }
  if (a === null || a === undefined || b === null || b === undefined || a.prototype !== b.prototype){
    return false;
  }
  return Object.keys(b).every(function(k){
    return similar(a[k], b[k]);
  });
}
let users = [
    {
       name: 'Steve',
       age: 42,
       pets: {
           dog: 'spike'
       },
       favouriteFood: 'apples'
    },
    {
       name: 'Steve',
       age: 32,
       pets: null,
       favouriteFood: 'icecream'
    },
    {
       name: 'Jason',
       age: 31,
       pets: null,
       favouriteFood: 'tacos'
    },
    {
       name: 'Jason',
       age: 31,
       pets: {
          cat: 'Jerry'
       },
       favouriteFood: 'bread'
    }
]
var testObj = {name:'Jason', age: 31, pets:{cat:'Jerry'}};
for(var i=0,u,l=users.length; i<l; i++){
  u = users[i];
  if(similar(u, testObj)){
    console.log('contains testObj');
    console.log(u);
  }
  else if(!similar(u, {pets:null}) && !similar(u, {pets:{dog:'spot'}})){
    console.log('not spot');
    console.log(u);
  }
}
```

`similar` will see if anything matches exactly that is not an Object, or if it is an Object it will see if `a` contains `b`, considering that `a` and `b` have properties and values at the same depth and `b` doesn't consist of properties that do not exist in `a`.